# Twitter Bootstrap Icon Bar Color Style

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, android-browser

I have a light Twitter Bootstrap menu, but want the button that toggles a drop down menu in phones and tablets to be dark. I've added the following style. It works in Firefox, but the style changes are not displaying in Android. Any idea what I need to do differently to make it display correctly in most if not all browsers?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse" style="color: #000000; background-color: #121212; 
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0d0d0d, #1a1a1a);">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Bootstrap combines both the navbar style and the icon-bar style. I cannot use LESS to modify one without modifying the other. I'd like for them to be different, because I have users complaining that they don't see a menu. It's there, just difficult to see in some devices because it blends in. Thank you for the hint about vendor CSS3 prefixes. I'll do some more research. Any suggestions on where to learn about CSS3 prefixes?

Comment: If you really want to learn them, I think Google might help you. But there are several tools that do it for you. Google something like "CSS prefixer" and you'll find them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of CSS3 background gradients is different between  browsers. To make sure that your code is supported in all browsers, you need to add vendor prefixes. Also, even with vendor prefixes, code for background gradients is different between browsers.

I will recommend [ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), great tool for cross-browser background gradients. There is many examples, and you may edit colors, direction of gradien, even add multiple gradients. Try it.

Comment: My CSS knowledge is very basic, so thank you for the explanation and the link!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to customize the colors of Twitter Bootstrap elements is using LESS.
You can customize them in the official page, download and do it in the variables.less file or try online tools like [Bootswatcher](http://bootswatcher.com).

This assures you don't have to use all the vendor CSS3 prefixes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the helpful hint. It doesn't solve my problem though. Please see my additional comment above. Thanks!